# Javascript variable doesn't update outside of loop, inside OK

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, variables, for-loop

I hope I'm not missing something obvious here.

```
function renderViews(containerId) {

    var root = '../Views/';
    var viewsDomStr = '';

    for (var i = 0; i < bundles.views.length; i++) {
            $.get(root + bundles.views[i], function (data) {
            viewsDomStr = viewsDomStr.concat(data);
        });
    }

    console.log(viewsDomStr);
    $('#' + containerId).append(viewsDomStr);

}
```

The problem is that the `viewsDomStr` is updated according to `data` from server only inside the `for` loop. For `console.log(viewsDomStr);` all I get is a reset to `''`.

Comment: Your get is an ajax request. The call back would not have executed by the time you get to your console.log

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the `$.get` request is asynchronous so the program continues on and doesn't wait for it. You want to use `viewsDomStr` inside the `$.get` function.

```
function renderViews(containerId) {

    var root = '../Views/';

    for (var i = 0; i < bundles.views.length; i++) {
        $.get(root + bundles.views[i], function (data) {
            console.log(data);
            $('#' + containerId).append(data);
        });
    }

    // This section runs before $.get is finished
}
```

EDIT: I've found that `viewsDomStr` is actually redundant. You are just adding text to the element so you can just add it to the `$.get`.

Comment: I don't want to use append method of jQuery for every turn of the loop. That's why actually I am using a concatenated string.

Comment: How's that? You can just use the data object you get back from the request, no need for viewsDomStr.

Comment: Yeah, I wanted to add it once but seems adding it one by one is the most optimum solution.

Answer (score 3):

The function you are calling is asynchron.

Try with

```
function renderViews(containerId) {

    var root = '../Views/';
    var viewsDomStr = '';

    function cb(){
        console.log(viewsDomStr);
        $('#' + containerId).append(viewsDomStr);
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < bundles.views.length; i++) {
            $.get(root + bundles.views[i], function (data) {
            viewsDomStr = viewsDomStr.concat(data);
            cb();
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since get method sends asynchronous request, you can check response every 1 sec using **setInterval**:

```
function renderViews(containerId) {

    var root = '../Views/';
    var viewsDomStr = '';

    var success = false;

    for (var i = 0; i < bundles.views.length; i++) {
            $.get(root + bundles.views[i], function (data) {
            viewsDomStr = viewsDomStr.concat(data);
            success = true;
        });
    }

    var t = setInterval(function(){
        if(success) {
            console.log(viewsDomStr);
            $('#' + containerId).append(viewsDomStr);
            clearInterval(t);
        }
    },1000);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The anonymous function of the `get` method will be asynchronous (as per the execution of `get` itself).

In short, it all happens too fast.